# How to raise gnome screen shield after logout using keyboard?

Tags: gnome3

I don't have mouse at hand, how do I log user in? The problem appears after shield comes down either by screen lock or after logout. Preferrably, this should not require maintaining extensions.

While I'm not at this computer right now, I was able to enter menu with: user list, screen lock and corner menu. But user list remains behind the shield.

Answer (score 1):

You can start typing the name of the user you want to log in as. This also works on the logged-in lock screen, start typing your password and the passwords text field will show up.